# Excel - Difference between 2 times including negatives (not #value)

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with 2 time fields. I want to get the difference between the 2 times to see if the 1st or 2nd duration was quicker and by how much. I have tried to do Duration1 - Duration2. That works fine except if Duration2 is longer, then it returns ########. I want it to return a negative value. Can someone help (see below):

[image]

Thanks
Rob

Thanks for the reply regarding TIMEVALUE. This has not worked. I tried TIMEVALUE on the fields as they were and got #VALUE. I then formatted the fields to show AM/PM but still get #VALUE:

[image]

Hi @BruceWayne. I tried your way but am getting #Value errors and the figures don't look correct:

[image]

Comment: I tweaked my Answer. Also, instead of adding information based on answers to the OP, you should add them as comments under the Answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
=IF(E1-G1<0,"-"&TEXT(ABS(E1-G1),"hh:mm:ss"),E1-G1)
```

Be sure to format this column as `Time` as well.

Also, I just saw this [related page](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006239_Displaying_Negative_Times.html) that should help.

> The easiest way to solve this problem is to just change the date system used by the workbook. This may sound goofy, but if you use a 1900 date system (which is the default for Windows versions of Excel), then you get the ############# in the cell. If, instead, you change to the 1904 date system (which is the default for Mac versions of Excel) then you'll see the correct negative elapsed time in your formula.

In the Advanced Options, tick "Use 1904 date system", and you can keep the simple `=E1-G1` formula:

[image]

Comment: Excellent find on the 1904 date system option!

Comment: @tigeravatar - It makes me wonder why they have different Default versions for Windows and Mac.  Perhaps in other aspects of Windows, they use the 1900 version, so in Excel they keep it that way to match?

Comment: Please note that while this 1904 solution does sort out the negative times it also adds 4 years to ALL dates! Bonkers. So I ticked this box, took a screenshot then unticked the box. No ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Excel can't handle negative time values, which is why they display improperly and error out other functions.  Can correct by getting the Absolute Value to guarantee a positive result:

```
=IF(E2<G2,"-"&TEXT(ABS(E2-G2),"hh:mm:ss"),E2-G2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the TIMEVALUE function, TIMEVALUE( time_value1 ) - TIMEVALUE( time_value2 )

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/timevalue.php

Comment: As OP noted, I also get `#VALUE` errors when trying this.